# Apache - set environment variable from proxy response header

Tags: amazon-s3, proxy, http-headers, apache2.4

I am proxying apache requests to s3 and I want to rewrite the response header into a new crafted header

this is my configuration:

```
SetEnvIf x-amz-meta-link "(.*)" DYN_CSS=$0
Header set Link "</static_assets/stylesheets/application-%{DYN_CSS}e.css>; rel=preload; as=stylesheet" env=DYN_CSS
```

s3 Header is configured to be x-amz-meta-link: css

I am expecting the header in the final response to be

```
 </static_assets/stylesheets/application-css.css>; rel=preloadas=stylesheet"
```

but what I get is (empty var)

```
</static_assets/stylesheets/application-.css>;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using version 2.4.10+ you can use:
I would suggest using the "expr=..." form of the Header directive and using `%{resp:x-amz-meta-link}` to get the response header value

`SetEnvIf` only reads request headers, runs before response headers are available, etc.

Comment: I am trying `Header set foo "expr=%{resp:x-amz-meta-link}e"`, but I am getting `foo: expr=(null)`

Comment: I also tried `Header set foo "expr=%{resp:x-amz-meta-link}"` but this doesn't even pass the apache reload

Comment: probably this : https://serverfault.com/questions/748326/apache-2-4-unrecognized-header-format